# Logic Error in loop statement program

Tags: java, logic

My program has a logic error in it. The program compiles correctly if I enter the data; 3 students, James 100, Ricky 98, Eric 70. If I enter James 100, Eric 70, and Ricky 98 it displays James and Eric as the top students which is incorrect any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindHighestScores {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String studentName = "";
    String topStudentName = "";
    String top2ndStudentName = "";
    int grade = 0;
    int topStudentGrade = 0;
    int top2ndStudentGrade = 0;
    int studentNumber = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
    studentNumber = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter a student name: ");
    topStudentName = input.next();

    System.out.print("Enter a students score: ");
    topStudentGrade = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter a student name: ");
    top2ndStudentName = input.next();

    System.out.print("Enter a students score: ");
    top2ndStudentGrade = input.nextInt();

    int count = 2;

    while (count < studentNumber) {

        System.out.print("Enter a student name: ");
        studentName = input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter a students score: ");
        grade = input.nextInt();

        if (grade > topStudentGrade) {
            grade = topStudentGrade;
            studentName = topStudentName;
        }
        if (grade > top2ndStudentGrade) {
            grade = top2ndStudentGrade;
            studentName = top2ndStudentName;
        }
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Top two students:" );

    System.out.println(topStudentName + "'s score is " + topStudentGrade);

    System.out.println(top2ndStudentName + "'s score is " + top2ndStudentGrade);
    input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the need of having the first two student inputs outside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
 if (grade > topStudentGrade) {
        grade = topStudentGrade;
        studentName = topStudentName;
    }
    if (grade > top2ndStudentGrade) {
        grade = top2ndStudentGrade;
        studentName = top2ndStudentName;
    }
```

It should be:

```
 if (grade > topStudentGrade) {
        topStudentGrade = grade; // these are backwards
        topStudentName = studentName;
    }else if (grade > top2ndStudentGrade) {
        top2ndStudentGrade = grade; //backwards again
        top2ndStudentName = studentName;
    }
```

Make the second statement an `else if` statement, otherwise you'll get the same result. You and to see if its the second highest if it's not the highest.

I'd also change the way you approach the input. After you get the number of students, create a loop that gets each students name and score. Then, you can write another function that you pass the student array into, which will check for the highest score.

Also, `count` should be set to `0`: `count = 0;`

And you don't need ANY of this, the way it's currently set up:

```
//This is the first set of inputs at the beginning of your program.
    System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
studentNumber = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter a student name: ");
topStudentName = input.next();

System.out.print("Enter a students score: ");
topStudentGrade = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter a student name: ");
top2ndStudentName = input.next();

System.out.print("Enter a students score: ");
top2ndStudentGrade = input.nextInt();
```